# ANDROID - Calendar multi date selection on touch (without `DatePicker`)

Tags: android, datepicker, multi-touch, multi-select

Is it possible to have a `CustomCalendar`created and enable a `multi-selection` kind of thing (like the photo gallery) to select `multiple dates on touch`?

What I was thinking is when oppening the `Activity`, the `Calendar`will show and in that phase it allows to choose several days of the current month by touching on the dates...

...is it 'do-able'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this http://codesfor.in/android-multi-datepicker-calendar-example/

Comment: This is an old issue. The way I did it was using a selector state for the item and keeping the state pressed for each one.
Thank you any way!